# What are we signing in the 'signature' field for OpenSea API

Tags: nft, opensea

There is a signature field here: https://docs.opensea.io/v2.0/reference/create-an-order

I understand the caller/lister has a private key. But what exactly is the content of the message that they're signing and putting in the signature field? Is it the whole message? The hash of the message? Something else?

I understand the whole API call is giving permission to OpenSea to transfer your NFT as long as it sells for the given price and the signature is there to prove that you're who you are.

Comment: Perhaps we need to follow the same signing process desribed here? https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/06transactions.asciidoc#the-elliptic-curve-digital-signature-algorithm